# Why position: absolute effects getBoundingClientRect()?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to build a custom video controls, with a progress bar allows users to jump to any position. My idea is:

1. Using the `getBoundingClientRect()` method to get the boundary coordinates of the progress bar container.
2. Finding click position via a mouse event method `e.clientX`.
3. Calculating the width of the progress bar according to the difference of the two positions

My problem is the return value of getBoundingClientRect(). In my understanding, coordinates obtained by this function and clientX function are both relative to the viewport, so I can determine where the mouse is clicked on the progress bar by doing some simple subtraction. But the actual operation is obviously not the case, the x-coordinate from getBoundingClientRect() is much smaller than it should be. I tested other elements, the x-coordinate of the leftmost element is actually negative!

I guess there's something wrong with the `position: absolute`. So I set the position property of the entire container(.player, wrapping video and controls) to be `relative`, then its width changed from the width of the video to taking up the entire body, but the x-coordinate returned by getBoundingClientRect() is correct, my progress bar is working fine.

So I want to know, why does the absolute position property actually affect the return result of the getBoundingClientRect() function? Or is something else affecting it？

My test browsers are Firefox and Chrome, here is my code:

```js
const media = document.querySelector('video');
const controls = document.querySelector('.controls');

const timerContainer = document.querySelector('.timer');
const timer = document.querySelector('.timer span');
const timerBar = document.querySelector('.timer div');

// Make a seek bar

const timerBarBound = timerContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(timerBarBound);

timerContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.clientX);
  let clickProcess = e.clientX - timerBarBound.x;

    if (clickProcess > 0 && clickProcess < timerBarBound.width) {
        let barProcess = timerContainer.clientWidth * (clickProcess  / timerBarBound.width);
        timerBar.style.width = `${barProcess}px`;
    }
});
```

```css
.player {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  display: flex;
}

button:before {
  position: relative;
  content: attr(data-operate);
}

button {
  position: relative;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 19px;
  flex: 1;
}

.timer {
  line-height: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  flex: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.timer div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 38px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.timer span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 19px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="player">
      <video>
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
      </video>
      <div class="controls">
        <button class="play" data-operate="P"></button>
        <button class="stop" data-operate="S"></button>
        <div class="timer"><div></div><span>00:00 / 02:00</span></div>
        <button class="rwd" data-operate="B"></button>
        <button class="fwd" data-operate="F"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/custom-player.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: have you looked into whether [`MouseEvent.offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) instead? "_The offsetX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the offset in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node._"

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tested this method you suggested, it is indeed more concise and can meet my needs, ignoring relationship between the boundary and the click position. It's awesome, thank you! But I still want to know why the absolute position affects the return value of the getBoundingClientRect(), because according to the documentation, its return value should only be relative to the viewport.@davidfong

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem, clicking the progress bar changes the progress to mouse position and the coordinates logged seem fine. What exactly is going wrong for you?

Comment: Are you certain that it isn't when you enter inspect mode on your browser that things don't seem right? My concern is that you don't seem to be doing any resizing if the viewport changes (or if there is any scrolling) and yet you are only reading the bounding client rect once at the start - and as you say both that and clientX are relative to the (current) viewport.

Comment: The only thing I can see is when the video is larger than the viewport and your scrolled to the right; you'll need to add the scrolling position (`window.scrollX`) in that case since `getBoundingClientRect` coords are relative to *viewport*, not document.

Comment: This is a lot of code that does not relate to the question being asked. I won't have time to help because it will take a lot of reading. You should start by creating the [simplest reproduction of the problem containing only relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which would make it easier for others to help you. I don't think you have narrowed the problem down enough.

Comment: I just built a very simple web page to test making a functional controls for the video. There is only one div element with class .player wrapping the video and  controls. The video width is 720px and the viewport width is over 1100px (even with the inspector turned on), so I am sure that the video is much smaller than the viewport, and there is no horizontal scroll bar on the page. I tried resize the page, from 150px to 1200px, nothing changed, the return value of getBoundingClientRect() is still weird, the (0,0) it is based on seems to be somewhere between the P and U keys. @tobiv

Comment: Sorry, my code is not concise enough. I only removed the JavaScript code that is not related to the problem, thinking that it should be concerned with some features of CSS, so I kept too much CSS code. After some more testing I removed all the decorative CSS and only kept the position and size related parts, I am sure this snippet(except the video, my video size is 720px x 306px and duration is two minutes) could reproduce my problem, the return value of getBoundingClientRect() is still not viewport based. I reposted the further simplified code, thanks for your comment.@JuanMendes

Comment: I *think* I can reproduce the issue now. It looks like the DOMRect being returned is that of the *empty* `player` container (with position:absolute) – if you remove the video source, you get the same coordinates as with the video in place. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getBoundingClientRect()` is being executed before the video has finished loading, thus the browser doesn't yet know its size. The `video` element seems to have a default size, so the DOMRect you get corresponds to that.

Wrap the call with a [`loadeddata` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event) on the video element, and it should work:

```js
const media = document.querySelector('video');
const controls = document.querySelector('.controls');

const timerContainer = document.querySelector('.timer');
const timer = document.querySelector('.timer span');
const timerBar = document.querySelector('.timer div');
let timerBarBound = {};

media.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
  timerBarBound = timerContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(timerBarBound);
}, false);

timerContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.clientX);
  let clickProcess = e.clientX - timerBarBound.x;

  if (clickProcess > 0 && clickProcess < timerBarBound.width) {
    let barProcess = timerContainer.clientWidth * (clickProcess  / timerBarBound.width);
    timerBar.style.width = `${barProcess}px`;
  }
});
```

```css
.player {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  display: flex;
}

button:before {
  position: relative;
  content: attr(data-operate);
}

button {
  position: relative;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 19px;
  flex: 1;
}

.timer {
  line-height: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  flex: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.timer div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 38px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.timer span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
      <video>
        <source src="https://static.videezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/055/291/original/20201011_savings_84.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <div class="controls">
        <button class="play" data-operate="P"></button>
        <button class="stop" data-operate="S"></button>
        <div class="timer"><div></div><span>00:00 / 02:00</span></div>
        <button class="rwd" data-operate="B"></button>
        <button class="fwd" data-operate="F"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tested your code and added a `loadeddata` event to make sure the video is loaded before using the `getBoundingClientRect()` function, it returned correct value, it completely solved my problem.

Comment: In addition, I have done a lot of testing myself, mainly about the CSS code, I found that if set `.controls{left: 50%}`  from relative length to absolute length, my problem can be solved, too. I haven't figured out why it works. After reading your answer, I think maybe it is the same reason —— the video loading is not completed, which affects the value of the left property of .controls. 

This problem has been bothering me for two days, now you made me understand the reason, thank you so much.